# Cannot connect to hive database using Apache spark 2.1.0

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-2.0

I am using spark 2.1.0 version and trying to establish a connection with Hive tables. My hive data warehouse is in /user/hive/warehouse in hdfs, by listing contents of that folder i can see all the dbname.db folders in it.
After some research i found that i need to specify the `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` in spark 2.x and i set it like this

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Hive Example")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
```

and now i am trying to print the databases

`spark.sql("show databases").show()`

but i am only seeing default databases,

```
+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
|     default|
+------------+
```

So i there any way i can connect the spark to the existing hive database? is there anything i am missing here?

Comment: Do you have a hive-site.xml file somewhere? this could override default settings.

Comment: Also, I suggest to use debug log: ``sc.setLoggerLevel("debug")``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `hive-site.xml` should be in classpath. Check [this](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/How-is-hive-site-xml-loaded-td11554.html) post. If you are using maven project then you can keep this file in resources folder.

Another way to connect to hive is using metastore uri.

```
val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Spark Hive Example")
.master("local[*]")
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please, why is yours working, whereas OP's `config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")` does not? What OP suggests is also suggested in the official documentation. Apparently, what is suggested officially does not work for many people...

Comment: Where in Spark official documentation, do you see this is possible to configure Hive like this?

Answer (score 0):

there is a hive-site.xml file in /usr/lib/hive/conf. copy this file to

/usr/lib/spark/conf
then you will see other databases. please follow the below steps.

1.open hive console and create a new database
hive>create database venkat;

2.close hive terminal

3.copy hive -site.xml file

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-site.xml        /usr/lib/spark/conf/hive-site.xml
```

4.check databases

```
sqlContext.sql("show databases").show();
```

I think it will helpful

Answer (score 0):

**step one:**
You should config like this under `Custom spark2-defaults`:
[image]

**step two:**
Write the following command from the command line:

```
import com.hortonworks.hwc.HiveWarehouseSession
import com.hortonworks.hwc.HiveWarehouseSession._
val hive = HiveWarehouseSession.session(spark).build()
hive.showDatabases().show()
```

[image]

Integrating Apache Hive with Spark and BI:
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/integrating-hive/content/hive_configure_a_spark_hive_connection.html

HiveWarehouseSession API operations:
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehousesession_api_operations.html